# bash: Match and replace user input with another array

Tags: bash, array, command-substitution

First of all, sorry for the heading. I'm not sure how to place my ambition in a few words. However, from a coding/scripting standpoint it should be pretty basic. Though, I somehow fail to achieve it :/

I have a bash script that awaits a user input (either via prompt or command-line argument). As there are only a few accepted answers I check them against an array. Let's call it 'packs' for now.
Each accepted answer resembles an easy and human-readable alias for something else. That would be declared in the array in the second line.

```
declare -a packs=('low', 'mid', 'high')
declare -a packcontent=('1+1+2', '2+2+3', '3+3+4')

parameters=${packcontent[xxx]}
```

The point where I fail is to resolve the first array with the second one. How do I get the index of the user's input in order to pass it in a variable?

Example: If the user says 'low', it should notice 'low' is the first (zeroth) element of the first array. Therefore 'parameters' should be assigned the first (zeroth) element of the second array.

```
parameters=1+1+2
```

I'm not sure if I miss an intermediate step or bash can't substitute that, but I lack any idea how I achieve that.

Hope my explanation of the issue wasn't that messy.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for bash associative arrays!

You can make arrays that take strings as indices. You might know them as "hashes" or "maps" from other languages. Consider the following:

```
$ declare -A packs
$ packs=( [low]='1+1+2' [mid]='2+2+3' [high]='3+3+4' )
$ parameters=${packs[low]}
$ echo $parameters
1+1+2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes the thing much better than expected.

Answer (score 0):

[wyrm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539888/116858) all well and good when using a recent release of `bash`, but for releases earlier than 4.0 (e.g. on macOS), you will have to rely on ordinary arrays.

Here's how you could do that:

```
packcontent=('1+1+2' '2+2+3' '3+3+4')
low=0 mid=1 high=2

parameters=${packcontent[mid]}
```

The value in `$parameters` will be `2+2+3` since that's what's at index 1 in `packcontent`.  The `mid` does not need to be prefixed with `$` ("`$mid`") as the array index is evaluated in an arithmetic context.

---

For `/bin/sh` (no arrays), you could possibly get away with

```sh
set -- '1+1+2' '2+2+3' '3+3+4'
low=1 mid=2 high=3

eval "parameters=\$$mid"
```

That is, the list of possible parameters is kept in `"$@"` and the correct one is referenced with the help of one of `$low`, `$mid` or `$high` when assigning to `parameters`. The assignment is carried out with `eval` which will get the string `parameters=$n` to evaluate, with `n` replaced by the value of `$mid` (in this case).